# How to distinguish website was opened by browser and software?

Tags: c#, browser

I have a link in winform. I press it to open new site on my browser. I call it by page A. In my website I have another link. It link to page A too. When winform open page A it'll be removed header but I open it by website, header will not be removed. In my way, I provide a link for winform. After link was click, there's session save this value. Then I check this session on website. if it's not null, header will be removed from website. Althought it work, but I enter this link on website, not through winform, the header still removed. I want to distinguish page A was opened on wensite and on winform. How to know?

This picture illustrate my idear

[image]

Comment: So you have a website which should hide a header when users come from your WinForm? You could simply pass a parameter to the website which tells it to hide its header.

Comment: I have to create link for winform, after this active, Have Session was created. Base on Session, I hide header, but It not exactly

Answer (score 0):

The correct and easy way to achieve this is to determine the Useragent String in Javascript and render the page accordingly (depending on your WinForm's UserAgent, Should be settable).

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html Shows examples how it's done with "normal" Browsers.